# How do we mock out dependencies with Jest per test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

Here's the [full minimal repro](https://github.com/magicmark/jest_question)

Given the following app:

> src/food.js

```js
const Food = {
  carbs: "rice",
  veg: "green beans",
  type: "dinner"
};

export default Food;
```

> src/food.js

```js
import Food from "./food";

function formatMeal() {
  const { carbs, veg, type } = Food;

  if (type === "dinner") {
    return `Good evening. Dinner is ${veg} and ${carbs}. Yum!`;
  } else if (type === "breakfast") {
    return `Good morning. Breakfast is ${veg} and ${carbs}. Yum!`;
  } else {
    return "No soup for you!";
  }
}

export default function getMeal() {
  const meal = formatMeal();

  return meal;
}
```

I have the following test:

> _*tests_*/meal_test.js

```js
import getMeal from "../src/meal";

describe("meal tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it("should print dinner", () => {
    expect(getMeal()).toBe(
      "Good evening. Dinner is green beans and rice. Yum!"
    );
  });

  it("should print breakfast (mocked)", () => {
    jest.doMock("../src/food", () => ({
      type: "breakfast",
      veg: "avocado",
      carbs: "toast"
    }));

    // prints out the newly mocked food!
    console.log(require("../src/food"));

    // ...but we didn't mock it in time, so this fails!
    expect(getMeal()).toBe("Good morning. Breakfast is avocado and toast. Yum!");
  });
});
```

How do I correctly mock out `Food` *per test*? In other words, I only want to apply the mock for the `"should print breakfast (mocked)"` test case.

I would also like to not change the application source code ideally (although maybe having `Food` be a function that returns an object instead would be acceptable - still can't get that to work either)

Things I've tried already:

- thread the `Food` object around through `getMeal` + use dependency injection into `formatMeal`

  - (the whole point of this approach IRL is that we don't want to thread `Food` around the whole app)
- manual mock + `jest.mock()` - it's possible the answer is here somewhere, but it's tough to control the value here and reset it per test due to import time weirdness

  - Using `jest.mock()` at the top would override it for every test case, and I can't work out how to then change or reset the value of `Food` per test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Short answer

Use `require` to grab a fresh module in every test function **after** setting up mocks.

```
it("should print breakfast (mocked)", () => {
    jest.doMock(...);
    const getMeal = require("../src/meal").default;

    ...
});
```

**or**

Turn `Food` into a function and put a call to `jest.mock` into module scope.

```
import getMeal from "../src/meal";
import food from "../src/food";

jest.mock("../src/food");
food.mockReturnValue({ ... });

...
```

### Long answer

There is a snippet in Jest [manual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#examples) that reads:

> Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to be in the same scope as the require/import statement.

The [same manual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) also states:

> If you're using ES module imports then you'll normally be inclined to put your import statements at the top of the test file. But often you need to instruct Jest to use a mock before modules use it. For this reason, Jest will automatically hoist jest.mock calls to the top of the module (before any imports).

ES6 imports are resolved in the module scope before any of the test functions execute. Thus for mocks to be applied, they need to be declared outside of test functions and before any modules are imported. Jest's Babel plugin will "hoist" `jest.mock` statements to the beginning of the file so they are executed before any imports take place. **Note that `jest.doMock` is [deliberately not hoisted](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).**

One can study the generated code by taking a peek into Jest's cache directory (run `jest --showConfig` to learn the location).

The `food` module in the example is difficult to mock because it is an object literal and not a function. The easiest way is to force a reload of the module every time the value needs to be changed.

### Option 1a: Do not use ES6 modules from tests

ES6 import statements must be module scoped, however the "good old" `require` has no such limitation and can be called from the scope of a test method.

```
describe("meal tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it("should print dinner", () => {
    const getMeal = require("../src/meal").default;

    expect(getMeal()).toBe(
      "Good evening. Dinner is green beans and rice. Yum!"
    );
  });

  it("should print breakfast (mocked)", () => {
    jest.doMock("../src/food", () => ({
      type: "breakfast",
      veg: "avocado",
      carbs: "toast"
    }));

    const getMeal = require("../src/meal").default;

    // ...this works now
    expect(getMeal()).toBe("Good morning. Breakfast is avocado and toast. Yum!");
  });
});
```

### Option 1b: Reload module on every invocation

One can also wrap the function under test.

Instead of

```
import getMeal from "../src/meal";
```

use

```
const getMeal = () => require("../src/meal").default();
```

### Option 2: Register the mock and call through to real functions by default

If the `food` module exposed a function and not a literal, it could be mocked. The mock instance is mutable and can be changed from test to test.

> src/food.js

```
const Food = {
  carbs: "rice",
  veg: "green beans",
  type: "dinner"
};

export default function() { return Food; }
```

> src/meal.js

```
import getFood from "./food";

function formatMeal() {
  const { carbs, veg, type } = getFood();

  if (type === "dinner") {
    return `Good evening. Dinner is ${veg} and ${carbs}. Yum!`;
  } else if (type === "breakfast") {
    return `Good morning. Breakfast is ${veg} and ${carbs}. Yum!`;
  } else {
    return "No soup for you!";
  }
}

export default function getMeal() {
  const meal = formatMeal();

  return meal;
}
```

> __tests__/meal_test.js

```
import getMeal from "../src/meal";
import food from "../src/food";

jest.mock("../src/food");

const realFood = jest.requireActual("../src/food").default;    
food.mockImplementation(realFood);

describe("meal tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it("should print dinner", () => {
    expect(getMeal()).toBe(
      "Good evening. Dinner is green beans and rice. Yum!"
    );
  });

  it("should print breakfast (mocked)", () => {
    food.mockReturnValueOnce({ 
        type: "breakfast",
        veg: "avocado",
        carbs: "toast"
    });

    // ...this works now
    expect(getMeal()).toBe("Good morning. Breakfast is avocado and toast. Yum!");
  });
});
```

Of-course there are other options like splitting the test into two modules where one file sets up a mock and the other one uses a real module or returning a mutable object in place of a default export for the `food` module so it can be modified by each test and then manually reset in `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 0):

@anttix answer is best, but here is another angle that might be useful in other scenarios.

[babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) allows `import Food from "./food";` to be over-ridden by the test.

First, `yarn add babel-plugin-rewire`

**babel.config.js**

```js
const presets = [
  [
    "@babel/env",
    {
      targets: {
        node: 'current',
      },
    },
  ],
];

const plugins = [ 
  "babel-plugin-rewire"
];

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```

**meal_test.js**

```
import getMeal from "../src/meal";
import Food from "../src/food";
import { __RewireAPI__ as RewireAPI } from "../src/meal";

describe("meal tests", () => {
  // beforeEach(() => {
  //   jest.resetModules();
  // });
  afterEach(() => {
    RewireAPI.__Rewire__('Food', Food)
  });

  it("should print dinner", () => {
    expect(getMeal()).toBe(
      "Good evening. Dinner is green beans and rice. Yum!"
    );
  });

  it("should print breakfast (mocked)", () => {
    const mockFood = {
      type: "breakfast",
      veg: "avocado",
      carbs: "toast"
    };
    RewireAPI.__Rewire__('Food', mockFood)

    expect(getMeal()).toBe("Good morning. Breakfast is avocado and toast. Yum!");
  });

  it("should print dinner #2", () => {
    expect(getMeal()).toBe(
      "Good evening. Dinner is green beans and rice. Yum!"
    );
  });
});
```